# How to create a Front end (VueJS) for an API created by using NodeJS + Express + MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I've created a REST API by using Express. All the info is stored in MongoDB and all the endpoints of an API return JSON.

**index.js (main)**

```
const express =     require('express');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
const mongoose =    require('mongoose');
const app =         express();

/* Connect to a DB */
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cars');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
/* Initialize routes */
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

/* Listening on port 3000 */
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000, function() {
    console.log('I\'m ready for requests...');
});
```

**/routes/api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router =  express.Router();
const Car =     require('../models/car');

router.get('/cars', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
        type: 'GET'
    });
});

router.post('/cars', function(req, res) {
    Car.create(req.body).then(function(car) {
        res.send(car);
    });    
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can implement Vue.js into my API?

Comment: If you just return JSON (which is common for a REST API) what for would you need a frontend framework then?

Comment: Firstly, because I'm learing VueJS. Secondly, I have a task which I have to solve with framework + websockets. So, are you able to help me?

Comment: What you are asking here doesn't make sense. It actually would negatively impact the performance of your REST Api since it has to load the Vue.js library without having any benefit from it. Also your question is way too broad. "How can I implement a library". Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If you want to learn vue.js their documentation is excellent for getting started: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/